# Swift SpriteKit 1度だけメソッドを動作させたい

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

メソッドを条件によって、呼び出すか止めるかを制御したいです。
今回作成しているゲームアプリでは、画面上部からitemBox(node)が下部へ落ちます。
そのitemBox(node)とspaceship(node)が接触した際に、item1をユーザーは取得します。
その後、再度itemBox(node)とspaceship(node)が接触を行うとitem1が重複してしまいエラーが発生します。
ですので、一度itemBox(node)とspaceship(node)が接触した場合はitemBox(node)の出現をストップしたいです。

まずこちらがitemBoxを出現させているメソッドです。
didBigen内の「timar」で呼び出します。

```
    timar = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
        self.addItemBox()
    })
```

itemBoxのメソッド↓

```
func addItemBox() {

    let itemBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "itemBox")
    let xHighest:CGFloat = self.frame.maxX + itemBox.size.width
    let xLowest: CGFloat = self.frame.minX - itemBox.size.width
    let random = CGFloat.random(in: xLowest...xHighest)
    itemBox.position = CGPoint(x: random, y: frame.width)
    itemBox.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

    itemBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: itemBox.frame.width)
    itemBox.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = itemBoxCategory
    itemBox.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | itemBoxCategory
    itemBox.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = spaceshipCategory
    addChild(itemBox)

    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: frame.width / -2 - 100, duration: 1.0)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    itemBox.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]))        
}
```

その後、下記メソッドでitemBox(node)とspaceship(node)が接触した際にitem1をユーザーが取得(addChild(item1))します。

```
func hit(itemBox: SKPhysicsBody, target: SKPhysicsBody) {
    guard let itemBoxNode = itemBox.node else { return }
    guard let targetNode = target.node else { return }
    let itemBoxFunc = ItemBoxFunc()

    if target.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
        itemBoxNode.removeFromParent()
        addChild(item1)
    }
}
```

一応別クラスにスイッチ的な変数を作成して、初期状態はON、itemBox(node)とspaceship(node)が接触した際はOFFにして、OFFの時にはitemBoxを出現させない、の様な仕様を試みたのですが上手くいきませんでした。

追記/item1の宣言コード

【クラス内】

```
var item1: SKSpriteNode!
```

【didMove内】

```
    self.item1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "item1")
    self.item1.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / -2 + 150, y: frame.height / -2 +  150)
    self.item1.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    self.item1.zPosition = 1.0
    self.item1.alpha = 0.5
    self.item1.name = "item1"
```

Comment: `item1`をどのように宣言・初期化しているのかが分かるようなコードを示してください。

Comment: @OOperさん、ご確認ありがとうございます。
質問内容にitem1の宣言方法を追記致しました。
ご確認のほど宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「一度だけメソッドを動作」させると言うよりも、「item1が重複してしまいエラーが発生」するのを防ぐ、と言うことが主眼であるように解釈しました。

ご提示いただいたコードを見る限り、関連する部分を改善することにより自然と防止できるようにする、と言った上手い書き方はなさそうなので、

- `item1`が何かの子ノードになっていたら実行しないようにする

と言うロジックを入れるのが簡単ではないかと思います。

`hit(itemBox:target:)`内のif文を次のように変更してみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
        if target.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory && item1.parent == nil {
            itemBoxNode.removeFromParent()
            addChild(item1)
        }
```

`item1.parent == nil`と言う条件は、「`item1`に親ノードがいない」つまり「`item1`をどこかの親ノードに`addChild`できる」と言うことを表しますので、それが成り立つときにだけ`{ }`内が実行されることになります。

Comment: ＠OOPerさん
ご回答頂きありがとうございます。
OOPerさんのアドバイスに従いコードを編集したところ、期待通りの動作を致しました。
問題解決の発想力が乏しく力不足を痛感いたします。
いつも適切なアドバイスありがとうございます。
引き続き宜しくお願い致します。